# What am I? Feel welcomed to answer

Tags: riddle, mathematics, word, wordplay, rhyme

> Hi!
>
> I am big business you should better not skip
>
> If I'm used longer you're in a relationship
>
> Also, I feel odd when there are 2k human beings
>
> My absence might hurt anothers feelings

*Who/What am I? Can you figure it out?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is

> A Handshake

I am big business you should better not skip

> Even the biggest of businesses follow the norm of a handshake greeting. (unless another norm replaces it, like Japan's bowing greet, but even that one can include a handshake)

If I'm used longer you're in a relationship

> A prolonged handshake turns into hand holding, a common gesture of couples.

Also, I feel odd when there are 2k human beings

> Greeting a crowd is normal, but handshaking a crowd can be quite awkward

My absence might hurt anothers feelings

> A first meeting without a handshake might be considered rude to the other person

Title:

> We are *welcomed* to try, which hints to something done as a greeting, also hinted by the `Hi!` at the start of the riddle

Comment: Yes!! Great Job!

Comment: "Also, I feel odd when there are 2k human beings". rot13(Lbhe ernfbavat vf tbbq gbb, ohg lbh fubhyq tbbtyr Unaqfunxvat yrzzn. Nyfb pbafvqre gung 2x crbcyr ner na rira ahzore.)

Answer (score 1):

My guess

> **hospital(ity)** (or patient?)

I am big business you should better not skip

> A robust civilisation should have a hospital of some kind to treat patients

If I'm used longer you're in a relationship

> If you are in a hospital for long while, then it probably means you need to go there often; you have built a sort of *relationship* to it.

Also, I feel odd when there are 2k human beings

> This could refer to the [recent pandemic](https://www.livemint.com/news/india/coronavirus-over-2-000-people-now-infected-globally-56-dead-in-china-11580012441423.html)

My absence might hurt anothers feelings

> Lack of hospitality (or patience) could hurt people’s feelings.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I'm looking for. But you might be on the right track. rot13(Vg unf fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu uhzna vagrenpgvbaf.)

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

> identity

I'm not too sure though.

1. I am big business you should better not skip

   > I believe this refers to either "corporate identity" (establishing a brand presence) or how corporations are utilizing personal information (i.e., identities) for targeted sales.
2. If I'm used longer you're in a relationship

   > Refers to how mathematical relationships (or functions) with identities have been studied for longer.
3. Also, I feel odd when there are 2k human beings

   > In a large crowd, one might feel a sense of loss of identity.
4. My absence might hurt anothers feelings

   > I think this refers to an algebraic structure without an identity element (where some theorems break down).  Or the absence of an individual (or their identity) may upset someone else.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for.  rot13(Vg unf fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu uhzna vagrenpgvbaf. Gurer ner (yvxr lbh abgvprq) ersreraprf gb zngu.)